# Is there a changes of codes if we use different kinds of printer? In printing barcode using bluetooth printer(Android Java)

Tags: android, zebra-printers

I tried these links:

https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/P25Demo

https://github.com/AlexanderKaraberov/Android-BluetoothPrinter-Demo

But doesn`t print barcodes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Different Bluetooth printers can use different codes based on manufacturer and model. You are better off starting with looking for an Android SDK from the printer manufacturer first. Also asking for tutorials or libraries is considered off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks for this post. I`m using Zebra EZ320. Can you share some codes or links pls?

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps for zebra-printers

> Start to finish, these steps will help you go from label novice to a printing pro:
>
> 1. If you do not have a previous experience with Zebra Printers, then I recommend the Getting Started with Printers and Apps document. This document walks you through setting up a Zebra printer out of the box, configuring its basic settings, and designing labels.
> 2. If Zebra printers are something you’re comfortable with but writing Android applications that print to them is a whole other story, read through the Getting Started with Android Development document. There is also sample code and demo apps available on GitHub and more information and discussions on the Printers page.
> 3. When creating printing applications, there are a few key points developers must keep in mind. These are outlined in Zebra’s Best Practices for Printing Applications. There is a recorded webinar that goes through these best practices and shows sample code on how they can be implemented. If you are in a hurry, the slide deck is included covering the main points.
> 4. Download the Link-OS SDK for implementation, demo sample code, and consultation. There are separate APIs in the SDK for Android and Android BTLE, and each API has at least one demo project.
>
>    5. Finally, review our API documentation to familiarize yourself with the full functionality of the Link-OS SDK. There’s a lot that it can do for you, so take advantage of everything it has to offer.

https://developer.zebra.com/blog/become-zebra-printing-android-developer-five-easy-steps

Comment: Thanks for this post. I`m using Zebra EZ320 and I didnt see Zebra EZ320 in the supported printers on there site.

Comment: If the printer is not supported, I dont think there will be a way to make it work.

Comment: Refer this link https://www.zebra.com/ap/en/support-downloads/printers/mobile/ez320.html